# I got an "a href" issue

Tags: href, filezilla

I just started coding and I have coded a whole simple website now. I used notepad++ and when i ran it in firefox it all work perfectly, after all I came to the hosting part the `<a href>` doesn't work on all the tabs I created (only some of the 2/5 are working). I used filezilla to upload the HTML files to the hostsite.

My question is, why does the href doesn't work on the uploaded domain but I does work when I just run it? I don't think the issue is on the coding, since it is fine when i open the HTML file in my browser (I am using "Hostinger.dk").

Comment: You need to share your code, otherwise it is impossible to give a good answer.

Comment: Maybe the web server is treating your file as a plain text file? Anyway, like @IgorJerosimić says - please post the HTML or better yet link to it on the problematic server.